# Sitecore User role to change Sort order

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I created a new user *editor* and a new role *Sitecore Editor* and assigned to that user. I want this user to be able to also set the sort order of an item, but none of those tabs are visible.

[image]
This role is a member of the the following:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should encourage your users to using the sorting buttons in the ribbon. They can be located in the `Home` tab.

[image: Home Tab - Item Sorting]

If you still want them to edit the `sortorder` field directly in the Content Editor then make sure that they have the `Standard fields` checkbox ticked in the `View` tab.

[image]

The downside of this is that it may expose too much data and all the standard fields tend to confuse the editors.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this. I want the user to only be able to add new items, edit & delete them. Do you think, I have added any unnecessary roles as seen from pic.

Comment: @Qwerty You shouldn't need to assign all those roles, e.g. `Author` inherits from `Sitecore Client Authoring` and `Sitecore Client Users` so just assigning the first role will automatically give them the other 2. Most likely `Author` and `Designer` will be enough: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/the_security_roles

Comment: That said, it's worth creating a custom role of your own that inherits from the Sitecore one and them applying the correct read/write/delete permissions to that.